# How to use Get-ChildItem with filter array in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

This script to remove some docs doesn't work:

```
$includeExtensions = @("*.doc", "*.docx")
get-childitem -Path "C:\somedir" -Include $includeExtensions | remove-item
```

Why not? And how do you specify an array of extensions which can then be passed as an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the results of Get-ChildItem to filter on just the extensions you want.

```
$includeExtensions  = @(".doc", ".docx")
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\somedir" | ?{$includeExtensions -contains $_.Extension} | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying it like so:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\somedir\* -Inc $includeExtensions | remove-item -whatif
```

From the docs on Get-ChildItem:

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
>   Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory,
>   such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory.

Comment: Yeah, it's on the backlog.  :-)