# How to use Get-ChildItem with excluding a list of items with an array in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, get-childitem

I want to use an array for the exclusion:

```
Remove-Item -Path "$InstallDir\Lang\*" -Exclude "de.txt", "en.txt"
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem "$InstallDir\Lang"  -EXCLUDE "es.txt", "de.txt"| Remove-Item
```

These both work fine.

Whereas

```
Get-ChildItem "$InstallDir\Lang\*" -Exclude "$Language" | remove-item
```

does not work.

I tried several ways ( e.g. [How to use Get-ChildItem with filter array in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597377/how-to-use-get-childitem-with-filter-array-in-powershell) or [How to exclude list of items from Get-ChildItem result in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207991/how-to-exclude-list-of-items-from-get-childitem-result-in-powershell)) but I can´t find a solution.
It seems as if `$Language` can't be interpreted by the command.

This is how `$language` is built:

```
[string]$Language = @('"de.txt"')
If ($PackageConfigFile.Language -notlike $Null) {
    foreach ($LIP in $PackageConfigFile.Language) {
        $Language += ",`n ""$LIP.txt"""
    }
}
```

$language has e.g. the following content

> "de.txt",
>
> "en.txt",
>
> "es.txt"

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

**Construct your `$Language` argument as an actual *PowerShell array***; what you attempted creates a *multil-line string* instead.

Creating that array should be as simple as:

```
$Language = $PackageConfigFile.Language -replace '$', '.txt'
```

`-replace`, with a collection (array) as the LHS, operates on each item in the collection individually; `'$', '.txt'` effectively *appends* `.txt` to the *end* (`$`) of each input item, and the resulting modified elements are collected in `$Language` as an *array*, of .NET type `System.Object[]`.

**Second:**

**Do not enclose `$Language`, your array argument, in `"..."`.**

```
Get-ChildItem $InstallDir\Lang\* -Exclude $Language | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

---

If you enclose an array variable in `"..."`, PowerShell converts it to a single *string*, composed of the array elements concatenated with the value of preference variable `$OFS`, which defaults to a *space*; e.g.:

```
PS> $arr = 'a', 'b', 'c'; "[$arr]"
[a b c]
```

---

For **readers coming from a UNIX / `bash` background**:

**PowerShell variables do NOT need to be double-quoted when they're passed to other commands, whatever they may contain** (spaces or other shell metacharacters).

When calling PowerShell-native functionality (cmdlets, functions, scripts), the variable's original type is preserved as-is (the ability to use the .NET Framework's rich type system is the core feature that exemplifies PowerShell's evolutionary quantum leap in the world of shells).

**Only use `"..."` if you explicitly want to pass a *string* to the target command.**

Answer (score 1):

```
$Language = @('de.txt')
If ($PackageConfigFile.Language -notlike $Null) {
    foreach ($LIP in $PackageConfigFile.Language) {
        $Language += "$LIP.txt" 
    } 
}
```